# To add GET parameters in Swagger

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger-ui, django-rest-swagger

Use [django rest framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and [django-rest-swagger](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger) in documentation of the methods it is not showing available GET parameters and the question is how can I set?

code:

```
# views.py
@api_view(['GET'])
def tests_api(request):
    """

    :param request:
    :return:
    """
    id = request.query_params.get('id')
    name = request.query_params.get('name')

    return Response({'user': name, 'text': 'Hello world'})

# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^api/v1/tests_api/$", tests_api),
]
```

http api:

```
GET https://127.0.0.1/api/v1/tests_api/?name=Denis&id=3

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
{
    "user": "Denis",
    "text": "Hello world"
}
```

now: 
[image]
example:
[image]

[Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/782070/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-get-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B2-swagger) version.

Answer (score 1):

Declare schema manually and specify fields there with location `query`

```
  schema = ManualSchema(fields=[
        coreapi.Field(
            "name",
            required=True,
            location="query",
            schema=coreschema.String()
        ),
    ]
  )
```

See [doc for details](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/coreapi/schemas/#manualschema)

Answer (score -2):

```
    urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/v1/tests_api/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<name>\w+)/$', tests_api),

]
```

[image]